# Automapper with linq how?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5, automapper-3

Ok, I'm really struggling with finding a good example of what I need to do. So, I'll ask here.

Let's say I have a entity class (EF) named Customer and a corresponding view-model class named CustomerViewModel.

Using AutoMapper, I have created the following mappings:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, Customer>(); 
 Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();
```

How would I modify the following code to make use of this mapping?

```
    public static List<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomers()
    {
        using (var context = new GCSBaseEntities())
        {
            var query = from c in context.Customers
                        select new CustomerViewModel
                        {
                            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                            Id = c.Id,
                            EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress,
                            FirstName = c.FirstName,
                            LastName = c.LastName,
                            MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
                            ModifiedDate = c.ModifiedDate,
                            Phone = c.Phone,
                            SalesPerson = c.SalesPerson,
                            Suffix = c.Suffix,
                            Title = c.Title,
                            FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName
                        };

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. In order to avoid the aforementioned error, you have to Add the call the .AsEnumerable() after Customers like so:

```
     return from c in context.Customers.AsEnumerable()
        select Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c);
```

I got this from this thread: [LINQ and AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770941/linq-and-automapper)

Answer (score 2):

When you register your mappings, you must provide any complex mapping operations that have to occur. In your case, I believe all your properties match up, except for `FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName`. Here's how your Customer-to-CustomerViewModel mapping should look:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
       .ForMember(custVm => custVm.FullName,
            mapper => mapper.MapFrom(cust => cust.FirstName + " " + cust.LastName));
```

You'll have to figure out how to shove the `FullName` prop from the ViewModel back into the `FirstName` & `LastName` fields on the EF class, though. But when you decide how to implement it, follow the pattern from above for the other mapping.

Your query can now be MUUUCH smaller:

```
using (var context = new GCSBaseEntities()) 
{
     return from c in context.Customers
            select Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c);
}
```

Comment: Graham, thanks for the answer, that helped. When I tried that, I get the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DemoMVCLookup.Models.PersonViewModel Map[PersonViewModel](System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

However, I found the following which seems to work: 

            using (var context = new DemoEntities())
            {
                var result = context.People.Project().To<PersonViewModel>();
                return result.ToList();

            }

Note, that I've changed the entities to simply. Any ideas?