# using Automapper with LINQ in Web Api get method

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have a small Web Api method. How can I map properties in GetBooks method with Automapper? I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223995/automapper-with-linq-how) .

I have tried

```
 return from c in db.Books select Mapper.Map<BookDTO>(c);
```

But it didnt work.
Here is my complete code;

```
     //GET: api/Books
      public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
      {
        var books = from b in db.Books
                    select new BookDTO()
                    {
                        Id = b.Id,
                        Title = b.Title,
                        AuthorName = b.Author.Name
                    };

        return books;
    }
```

Book.cs

```
 public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

BookDTO.cs

```
 public class BookDTO
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
   }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: "But not succesfull" is not a description of the problem.

Comment: You are right. I was in a hurry thats why I wrote like that. I mean I tried the methods on the link I have given. And it didnt work. I implemented this code on to mine.    return from c in context.Customers
            select Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel>(c);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Config Map between `Book` and `BookDTO` in **Global.asax.cs** or **Startup.cs** file:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>();
   ```
2. Map `db.Books` in `GetBooks()` method:

   ```
   using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

   ...

   public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
   {
       return db.Books.ProjectTo<BookDTO>();
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, It worked, really amazing. Do you have any idea about How does Automapper knows BookDTO.AuthorName is Book.Author.Name ?

Comment: @OneNiceFriend:  If for any property on the destination type a property does not exist on the source type, AutoMapper splits the destination member name into individual words (by PascalCase conventions), This link explains it better: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening

Answer (score 1):

You need projection. See [Automapper - Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthorName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Author.Name));

IEnumerable<Book> books = db.Books.Cast<Book>();
// assuming Books implements IEnumerable
BookDTO result = Mapper.Map<Book, BookDTO> books;
```

I'm not sure if you need the projection lines for properties Id and Title. Read the documentation of AutoMapper to see what defaults it uses.