# Automapper and Linq with joined tables, populating ViewModel properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, viewmodel, automapper

Having just figured out how to populate my ViewModel from a model using Automapper, I am now onto the next challenge – populating the ViewModel properties from a joined table.

The image below depicts my simple database.

[image]

My ViewModel class is defined as:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SuffixId { get; set; }
    public string PersonStatus { get; set; }
    public string PersonPreference { get; set; }

    public virtual Suffix Suffix { get; set; }
}    enter code here
```

Note the additional fields of PersonStatus and PersonPreference that will come from joining PersonInfo to Person. 
Here is the code I use to instantiate my mapping configuration:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<PersonViewModel, Person>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
```

And now the code to populate the ViewModel

```
        List<PersonViewModel> persons = null;
        using (var context = new DemoEntities())
        {
            persons = (from p in context.People.AsEnumerable()
                       join i in context.PersonInfoes on p.Id equals i.PersonId
                    select Mapper.Map<PersonViewModel>(p)).ToList();
            return persons;
        }
```

How would I populate the two joined properties (PersonStatus and PersonPreference) from this setup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you joining PersonInfoes at all?  EF will handle this for you automatically and automapper will map it.

Comment: First a few questions: why the `AsEnumerable()` and how do you get one (of many) `PersonInfo`s?

Comment: Well, first, it's just a simple example I threw together so that I could pose the question. But Scottie, you say that AM will do it automatically. Can you elaborate? btw, person to personinfo is actually 1 to 1, not 1 to many. I'm trying to simulate a business rule we have on another system with this example. 

Gert, I was running into an error without the AsEnumerable(), I found this link which helped me resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770941/linq-and-automapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoMapper can automatically flatten an object structure if the source and target classes meet some requirements.

- The source class, the class that the mapping starts from, should have reference property to the related class. In you case: `Person.PersonInfo` (1:1, but n:1 will also work).<sup>1</sup>
- The target class should contain property names that allow AutoMapper to resolve the property path to the referenced object. in your case: `PersonViewModel.PersonInfoStatus`, so AutoMapper will see that there's a property `PersonInfo` in the source object and a property `Status` in the referenced object.

If you've got these things in place, you can do

```
persons = context.People.Project().To<PersonViewModel>().ToList();
```

The `Project().To` syntax is a relatively new API that allows working on `IQueryable`s. For more details see [Does AutoMapper support Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2212126/861716).

You will see that this sends a JOIN query to the database.

---

<sup>1</sup>*AutoMapper can also aggregate/flatten associated collections, but that's a different chapter.*